# POST request with sockets

Tags: c++, sockets, http-headers, http-post

I have to send post-request using pure sockets in c++. I can't understand where to send the body  of the request:

```
int *binary = new int[bufferLength];
...

std::stringstream out(data);
out << "POST /push1_pub?id=game HTTP/1.1\n";
out << "Host: http://0.0.0.0:80\n";
out << "Content-Length: ";
out << bufferLength*sizeof(int);
out << "\r\n\r\n";
out << binary;

if (socket.send(data.c_str(), data.size()) == -1)
{
    std::cout << "Failed to send headers\n";
}
else
{
    // Send request body
    socket.send(reinterpret_cast<char*>(binary), bufferLength*sizeof(int));
    // Get the answer of server
    char buf[1024];
    std::cout << socket.recv(buf, 1024) << std::endl;
    std::cout << buf << std::endl;
}
```

But in `buf` after sending body I have:

```
<html>
<head><title>400 Bad Request</title></head>
<body bgcolor="white">
<center><h1>400 Bad Request</h1></center>
<hr><center>nginx</center>
</body>
</html>
```

What could be wrong here?

---

**upd**:

New headers I have written due to your comments:

```
std::string data;
std::stringstream out(data);
out << "POST /push1_pub?id=game\r\n";
out << "Host: http://localhost\r\n";
out << "Content-Length: ";
out << bufferLength << "\r\n";
out << "\r\n\r\n";
out << binary;
```

Still have same problem.

---

**upd2**

With this command: `curl -s -v -X POST 'http://0.0.0.0/push1_pub?id=game' -d 'Test'` Everything works fine and post request is generated and sent right.

Comment: @SLaks I'm not able to run it under Linux?

Comment: Although it's not the real problem, you should terminate each header with a [CRLF](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec4.html#sec4.1), not just CR. Also, you shouldn't specify `HTTP/1.1` unless you support [chunked encoding](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec3.html#sec3.6.1). (Note the *MUST* line at the end of that section.)

Comment: As to your later problem with the request body: I can't think of any way `bufferLength*sizeof(int)` could be sensible. The content length is the number of *bytes* of content you are sending. What would the number of bytes your platform uses to store an integer have to do with the number of bytes in your request? Your request must be in the format the server accepts, which will have nothing whatsoever to do with your local binary integer format.

Comment: This won't work either: `socket.send(reinterpret_cast<char*>(binary), bufferLength*sizeof(int));` How can the server make sense of this? It has no idea how your platform stores integers. It doesn't even know how many bytes each integer is. Is "00,00,00,01" four integers or one integer? And if it's one integer? Is it a 1? Or is a 1 represented as "01,00,00,00"? How can the server know what you mean? You have to assemble the request in the format the server accepts.

Comment: @DavidSchwartz Can you help with pointing to the docs, because now I don't really know in what side to look.

Comment: Honestly, I'd start by reading the entire HTTP 1.1 specification. If you don't want to have to implement chunked encoding, then read HTTP 1.0. But it seems like you also don't understand the basic notions of server/client computing as you seem to think the server will understand whatever you send it. (I hope that doesn't come across as rude, I'm just being honest. Maybe it was just a silly oversight, but it looks like you don't have a grasp on the basic concept that you *must* send the data in the format the server expects, not the format your platform likes to store it in.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your host line is wrong. It should be a simple hostname, e.g. "localhost" or "example.com", not the `http://0.0.0.0:80` URL you've got now.

The host line is used by the webserver to identify which of potentially THOUSANDS of sites hosted on a single IP is being requested. The port number is also useless, since by the time you're sending the HTTP headers, the TCP connection has already been established. And since you're already doing an HTTP request, there's no need to redundantly specify the protocol in use.

Comment: Okay, thanks. But where exact to send `binary` array - the body of the request? I'm adding it to headers and also trying to send after sending headers. p.s. there is still 400 error.

Comment: You have a number of issues in your code, some major and some minor. You really should start by studying the [HTTP specification](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616.html) if you insist on writing your own HTTP client implementation. But it's much more sensible to use one that's already done. HTTP is really not a simple protocol